# Regex to find lines where 8th position isn't a semicolon

Tags: regex

I have a text file that should contain only entries in the form of 8 digits then a semicolon and then some more text:

`12345678;some more text`

I would like to find those entries that don't start with eight numbers and are then followed by a semicolon. I can find the positive entries with

`^[0-9]{8};.*`

But I am not sure how to "reverse" my regex...

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks all.

Comment: Why not just negate your condition in your language? Seems to be most easiest way

Comment: I was using this regex in notepad++, so am not wrapping the regex in .net or java etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
^(?![0-9]{8};)
```

This regex only matches if it's not possible to match 8 digits and a semicolon at the start of the string (using a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

You can add `.*` after the lookahead if you want the regex to actually match the text in that line if this condition is fulfilled. Without it, you just get a True/False result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the regex library used: `^[0-9]{8}[^;].*`

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach would be to invert match condition rather creating invert regex

```
grep -v '^[0-9]{8};' file
```